# HtAccess: Force WWW but keep subdomain mask

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to force .www so Google doesn't pick up my website twice but when I do my subdomains no longer mask using `[P]`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((www\.)?)domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/website/%1$1 [L,NC,P]
```

When I visit a masked domain it simply just redirects and no longer masks. If I take out the top part the subdomains work fine but it then doesn't force .www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order of rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/website/%1/$1 [L,P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When visiting a subdomain it doesn't mask the URL using [P] then...any ideas?

Comment: That simply means `mod_proxy` isn't enabled for subdomain

Comment: 'mod_proxy' is enabled just it doesn't mask when I add the force .www

Comment: hmm, that seems to be wiping out the subdomain on redirect.

Comment: Didn't get, what does that mean?

Comment: When I use a subdomain it redirects to the actual URL and doesn't mask it using [P] when using the force on the .www - if it makes it easier, could I just force no .www, and maybe that won't wipe out the URL mask.

Comment: I retested this whole code and it worked fine. Make sure you test in a new browser.

Comment: That actually works now, thank you. Sorry to be a pain, but how would I force it so there was no www?